# South migration: delete all migration files (00*_*) and start from 0001, while keeping the original data

Tags: heroku, deployment, migration, django-south

I am developing web systems using Django and they are deployed on Heroku. After the system goes production, all database data and the migration files (i.e., the 00*_* files) have to be retained. The followings are my procedure to perform database migration and deployment:

1. For the first deployment, perform `manage.py makemigrations` locally and push to Heroku.
2. Perform `manage.py migrate` on Heroku.

If models are changed later:

3. Perform `makemigrations` locally and push to Heroku.
4. Perform `migrate` on Heroku.

Steps 3 and 4 are repeated if models are changed.

As the system evolves, there are more and more migration files. I am wondering: after a successful migration and deployment, can I just delete all migration files and start like a fresh one? That is:

1. For the first deployment, perform `makemigration` locally and push to Heroku.
2. Perform `migrate` on Heroku.
3. Delete all local migration files.
4. Perform `makemigrations` locally to create seemingly start-up migration files.

Change models:

5. Perform `makemigration` locally and push to Heroku.
6. Perform `migrate` on Heroku.

Steps 3 to 6 are repeated if models are changed.

Is the above procedure correct?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For each of your app:

1) Pretend to rollback all existing migrations:

```
./manage.py migrate app zero --fake
```

The `zero` argument indicates that we rollback to the first migration. You can confirm all migrations have been rollbacked by running `./manage.py migrate app --list`.
The `--fake` option signals we should not actually run the migrations, but nonetheless mark the migrations as having been run: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/django-admin/#django-admin-option---fake

2). Delete migration files

```
git rm app/migrations/*
```

3) Create a new migration file

```
./manage.py makemigrations app
```

4) Pretend to run the new migration

```
./manage.py migrate app --fake
```

As in 1), step 4) does not actually run the migrations.

EDIT: added some explanations and fixed the `zero` argument.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Would you please elaborate more on steps 1 and 4? What do they mean?

Comment: Got it. One last question: what would be the sequence if I need to change the model? 1 (remote) --> 2 (local) --> Change the app's model --> 3 (local) --> push to remote --> 4 (remote). Is this correct? Do I need to remove the "--fake" at step 4 to actually run the migration?

Comment: I suggest you make all required modifications to the model prior to 1), as you usually do. Just run makemigration locally and migrate on heroku.

Comment: Its probably worth noting that command 1 and 4 need to be run on the server. 
I got everything working on my dev machine, but after deployment the django_migrations table didn't reflect the changes.