# django, squash migrations, too many circular dependencies

Tags: django, migrate

I tried to squash migrations.

Unfortunately there are just too many circular dependencies.

Is there a way to start over the migrations (although my project is already deployed in production) than trying to squash the migrations?

I don't have to worry about some unknown developer using my project because it's a private project.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Yes, there is a way. See [this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32074791/south-migration-delete-all-migration-files-00-and-start-from-0001-while-k/32871513#32871513). In a nusthell:

```
# 1) Fake migrations back to 0
./manage.py migrate app zero --fake

# 2) Delete migrations files
git rm "app/migrations/*"

# 3) Create new migration file
./manage.py makemigrations app

# 4) Pretend to run the new migration
./manage.py migrate app --fake
```

Comment: I actually figured it might be more difficult starting over to resolve circular dependencies. (it may well depend on your migration history). but Yes that is definately the answer to my op.

Comment: Actually, when there are circular dependencies, above method would create migrations that would solve the circular dependencies automatically right?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by circular dependencies; do you mean migrations that depend on each other both ways? If yes, the suggested method gets rid of all migrations, thus of this kind of circular dependencies as well.

Comment: Yes, @eugene, the `makemigrations` command in step 3 seems to be smart enough to avoid circular dependencies between the migrations it creates. It will create more than one migration per app to avoid circular dependencies.

Comment: I've tried this on my project and I fail with circular deps across a bunch of apps. Any ideas on how to extend this to more than one app? @RégisB.

Comment: If this solution doesn't work for you, you probably have a different problem :) I suggest you create a new question.

Comment: I am guessing if you are proceeding with this method on a team project, you have to tell everyone and make sure they follow these steps (or write a git hook for this particular commit).